# Parse text/html to application/json with restTemplate in java

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, spring-mvc

Here is my code:

```
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);
        MultiValueMap<String, String> map= new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();
        map.add("xx","xx");
        HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>> request = new HttpEntity<>(map, headers);
        ResponseEntity<String> response = new RestTemplate().postForEntity( url, request ,String.class);
```

Here is my response:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
 <html>
 <body onLoad="xx">
 <form action='xxx' method="post" name="aspForm" >
 <input type="hidden" name="responseMessage" value='Successfully Registered'/>
 <input type="hidden" name="url" value='xxxx'/>
 <input type="hidden" name="status" value='SUCCESS'/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

How to convert those name and value pairs from html response to JSON?

Comment: Why don't you make changes in the service to return json instead of html

Comment: This is a little "lite" on the explanation to  fully understand the goal here.  If you are trying to send a **JSON `String`** from an **`.html` Page** back to the server to which you are connecting - there are hundreds of SO Answers about sending **JSON** from a client to a server.  I'm sorry, I hope I don't sound rude, not my intention...  I cannot tell exactly ***which part*** (and where) your data needs to be converted.

Comment: Dear Alien, When I hit a third party API with the above form_url_encoded, i am getting the above specified html response. I need to consume the response and need to do some business operations. Hope you understood now.

Comment: Dear @Y2020-09 , The solution given below is the one I am looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be achieved using Jsoup and Jackson object mapper:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;

Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
    
    String responseMessage = doc.body()
            .getElementsByAttributeValue("name", "responseMessage")
            .first()
            .attributes()
            .get("value");
    
    String status = doc.body()
            .getElementsByAttributeValue("name", "status")
            .first()
            .attributes()
            .get("value");
    
    String url = doc.body()
            .getElementsByAttributeValue("name", "url")
            .first()
            .attributes()
            .get("value");
    
    Response response = new Response();
    response.setResponseMessage(responseMessage);
    response.setStatus(status);
    response.setUrl(url);
    
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    
    String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(response);
    
    System.out.println(json);
```

Output:

```
{"responseMessage":"Successfully Registered","status":"SUCCESS","url":"xxxx"}
```

**Update:**

If it's needed to convert HTML string without manual webscraping, it's also possible (but will work for XHTML only I suppose, because parser will break on non-XML-compliant markup).

POM dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.moxy</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.2</version>
    <type>jar</type>
 </dependency>
```

Bean definition (getter/setter skipped):

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "html")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Response {

    @XmlPath("body/form/input[@name='url']/@value")
    private String url;

    @XmlPath("body/form/input[@name='status']/@value")
    private String status;

    @XmlPath("body/form/input[@name='responseMessage']/@value")
    private String responseMessage;

}
```

Create message converter:

```
private static HttpMessageConverter<Object> createXmlHttpMessageConverter() throws JAXBException {
    MarshallingHttpMessageConverter xmlConverter = new MarshallingHttpMessageConverter();
   // I added lot of mediatypes, leave necessary ones
    xmlConverter.setSupportedMediaTypes(Arrays.asList(
            MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.TEXT_HTML, MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN, MediaType.TEXT_XML
    ));
    Jaxb2Marshaller jaxb2Marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
    jaxb2Marshaller.setClassesToBeBound(Response.class);
    // without this jaxb will complain about doctype in the beginning
    jaxb2Marshaller.setSupportDtd(true);
    xmlConverter.setMarshaller(jaxb2Marshaller);
    xmlConverter.setUnmarshaller(jaxb2Marshaller);
    return xmlConverter;
}
```

REST template initialization:

```
RestTemplate rest = new RestTemplate();
rest.getMessageConverters().add(0, createXmlHttpMessageConverter());
```

Also you'll need to set MOXy as JAXB provider. I used for this code

```
System.setProperty(JAXBContext.JAXB_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory");
```

but it can be done also in other ways.

This all will allow you to perform call:

```
Response response = rest.postForEntity(url, request, Response.class);
```

And from Response instance it should be trivial to retrieve JSON using Jackson.

Comment: Yeah Alexandra , I agree with your answer. We can do the same by using HtmlUnit framework's HtmlPage object as well. The code you have provided is nothing but "Webscraping". Is there any other way we can catch HTML response from an API to JSON? Thanks :)

Comment: Updated answer with another soluton

Comment: your efforts are much appreciated.. thank you, my friend.. :-)